# JavaScript; Copy text to the beginning of input field when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<span class="name">Peter</span><br>
<span class="name">Harald</span><br>
<span class="name">George</span><br>
<span class="name">Sabrina</span><br>

<input type="text" value="This is a test!" name="message" id="input">
```

What I need to do: If I click on a string whose `class="name"` "copy" the text in it and insert it to the beginning of `value=""`.

Means:

When clicking on `<span class="name">Sabrina</span>`

change

`This is a test!` in the input field

to

`SabrinaThis is a test!`

Do you have an idea how to do it? Can I use JavaScript or do I need jQuery?

Comment: Can do it either way. Break this down into various parts....how to create event and get the element event occurred on in the handler.....how to get it's text....and how to modify value of a specific input. Then research each part to get some code to start with

Comment: this whole question is too broad. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service

Comment: you don't need jQuery, all jQuery does (although it does it rather well IMHO) is provide slightly more convenient ways of doing things you can already do in JavaScript. It's simply a JavaScript library. Ergo it cannot do anything you can't already do in JavaScript. Sometimes it makes those jobs easier or shorter, that's all.

Comment: i agree with @charlietfl. this is really simple with javascript and or jquery. you just need to know some basics to do that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have an idea how to do it? Can I use JavaScript or do I need
>   jQuery?

I'm assuming you asked this because you primarily want this with plain JavaScript.

Here is how you do it **without** JQuery:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.name').forEach(function(elem){
 elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
   document.querySelector('#input').value = this.innerText + document.querySelector('#input').value;
  });
});
```

```html
<span class="name">Peter</span><br>
<span class="name">Harald</span><br>
<span class="name">George</span><br>
<span class="name">Sabrina</span><br>

<input type="text" value="This is a test!" name="message" id="input">
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are thinking of a jQuery solution you can try the following:

```js
var text = $('#input').val();
$('.name').click(function(){
  $('#input').val($(this).text() + ' ' + text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="name">Peter</span><br>
<span class="name">Harald</span><br>
<span class="name">George</span><br>
<span class="name">Sabrina</span><br>

<input type="text" value="This is a test!" name="message" id="input">
```

If you are comfortable with Vanilla JS:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
document.querySelectorAll('.name').forEach(function(span){
  span.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('input').value = this.textContent + ' ' + text;
  });
});
```

```html
<span class="name">Peter</span><br>
<span class="name">Harald</span><br>
<span class="name">George</span><br>
<span class="name">Sabrina</span><br>

<input type="text" value="This is a test!" name="message" id="input">
```

Comment: this is pretty much the opposite of what was asked. The idea was to take the text from the span and add it to some existing text in a textbox, not add some text to the span

Comment: No problem. Now it's the best solution because it resets the value each time rather than appending the extra values infinitely like most of the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $input = $('#input');
  $('.name').click(function() {
    $input.val($(this).text() + $input.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<span class="name">Peter</span><br>
<span class="name">Harald</span><br>
<span class="name">George</span><br>
<span class="name">Sabrina</span><br>

<input type="text" value="This is a test!" name="message" id="input">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Edit:

Or by vanilla JS (without any libraries):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  document.querySelectorAll('.name').forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
      input.value = this.textContent + input.value;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<span class="name">Peter</span><br>
<span class="name">Harald</span><br>
<span class="name">George</span><br>
<span class="name">Sabrina</span><br>

<input type="text" value="This is a test!" name="message" id="input">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the [function parameter](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) of the `.val()` function for this:

So you can get the current value of the input field and concatenate it with the text of the clicked span

```js
$('.name').on('click', function() {

  var text = $(this).text();
  $('#input').val(function(index, value) {
    return text + value;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="name">Peter</span><br>
<span class="name">Harald</span><br>
<span class="name">George</span><br>
<span class="name">Sabrina</span><br>

<input type="text" value="This is a test!" name="message" id="input">
```

Answer (score 1):

with **jQuery** :

```js
$('.name').on("click", function() {
    var name = $(this).text();
    $("#input").val(name + " " + $("#input").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="name">test</span>
<input type="text" value="This is a test!" name="message" id="input">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var initialVal = $("input").val();
    $("span.name").click(function(){
     $("input").val($(this).text() + initialVal);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<span class="name">Peter</span><br>
<span class="name">Harald</span><br>
<span class="name">George</span><br>
<span class="name">Sabrina</span><br>

<input type="text" value="This is a test!" name="message" id="input">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why to specify `span` in the selector? And if there are more inputs in the page, this code will change them!